# Get element in a list Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using a css selector via chrome to get an image on a webpage but it returns a list with one elements that contains a long string with one of the element that I'm looking for. How can I get the image with the "data-src" tag.

my code

```
image = soup.select("#articulo_contenedor > figure > img")
```

returns

```
<img alt="En primera fila, de izquierda a derecha: Luis Salvador (alcalde de Granada); Luis Garicano (eurodiputado); Inés Arrimadas (portavoz en el Congreso); Edmundo Bal (portavoz adjunto); Marta Martín (diputada); y Begoña Villacís (vicealcaldesa de Madrid)." data-src="//ep01.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2019/12/07/actualidad/1575740947_516512_1575745986_noticia_normal.jpg" data-srcset="//ep01.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2019/12/07/actualidad/1575740947_516512_1575745986_noticia_normal_recorte1.jpg 1960w, //ep01.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2019/12/07/actualidad/1575740947_516512_1575745986_noticia_normal_recorte2.jpg 720w, //ep01.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2019/12/07/actualidad/1575740947_516512_1575745986_noticia_normal.jpg 980w" height="600" onload="lzld(this)" src="//ep00.epimg.net/t.gif" srcset="//ep00.epimg.net/t.gif 200w" width="980"/>
```

but I want to extract the first "data-src"

I've tried a lot of combinations, select_one, get_text(), find, findall, but I keep getting return type none.

Thanks

Comment: Try with `.find_next_sibling()`

Comment: Do you want to select first `<img>` tag with `data-src=` attribute? You can do `image = soup.select_one("#articulo_contenedor > figure > img[data-src]")`

Comment: Thanks but that returns the full tag same as I have

Comment: .find_next_sibling() returns the same as I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
image = soup.select("#articulo_contenedor > figure > img")
src = image[0]['data-src']
```

Comment: Thank you, so the select() creates the list and then find the tag in list.

Comment: @JohnnyQ yes!, for more img tags ,you can simply iterate through the list.